# amCharts Maps not loading circles on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, json, amcharts

I am having an issue with amCharts maps where every time I refresh my page my circles go away, but I can zoom in and the circles show up.

I am unsure what to do and if it is because of this wonky "custom" CMS that my company uses or not. I have tried running it on my own site and it is still doing the same thing. I am rather new to amCharts and javascript.

```
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create map instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

// Set map definition
chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

// Set projection
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

// Create map polygon series
var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());

// Exclude Antartica
polygonSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];

// Make map load polygon (like country names) data from GeoJSON
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;

// Configure series
var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#F0F0F0");

// Create hover state and set alternative fill color
var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#cccccc");

// Zoom control
chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

// Add image series
var imageSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
imageSeries.mapImages.template.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";
imageSeries.mapImages.template.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
imageSeries.mapImages.template.propertyFields.url = "url";
imageSeries.data = [ {
...

// add events to recalculate map position when the map is moved or zoomed
chart.events.on( "mappositionchanged", updateCustomMarkers );

// this function will take current images on the map and create HTML elements for them
function updateCustomMarkers( event ) {

  // go through all of the images
  imageSeries.mapImages.each(function(image) {
    // check if it has corresponding HTML element
    if (!image.dummyData || !image.dummyData.externalElement) {
      // create onex
      image.dummyData = {
        externalElement: createCustomMarker(image)
      };
    }

    // reposition the element accoridng to coordinates
    var xy = chart.geoPointToSVG( { longitude: image.longitude, latitude: image.latitude } );
    image.dummyData.externalElement.style.top = xy.y + 'px';
    image.dummyData.externalElement.style.left = xy.x + 'px';
  });

}

// this function creates and returns a new marker element
function createCustomMarker( image ) {

  var chart = image.dataItem.component.chart;

  // create holder
  var holder = document.createElement( 'div' );
  holder.className = 'map-marker';
  holder.title = image.dataItem.dataContext.title;
  holder.style.position = 'absolute';

  // maybe add a link to it?
  if ( undefined != image.url ) {
    holder.onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = image.url;
    };
    holder.className += ' map-clickable';
  }

  // create dot
  var dot = document.createElement( 'div' );
  dot.className = 'dot';
  holder.appendChild( dot );

  // create pulse
  var pulse = document.createElement( 'div' );
  pulse.className = 'pulse';
  holder.appendChild( pulse );

  // append the marker to the map container
  chart.svgContainer.htmlElement.appendChild( holder );

  $(holder).tooltip({});

  return holder;
}
</script>
```

I want the page to load with the circles showing up and not just the map. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can zoom in and the circles show up.

That was an important hint. Also since you have the same issue on your site as well as the CMS, the CMS is not the issue.

Right now you only have:

```js
chart.events.on( "mappositionchanged", updateCustomMarkers );
```

You'll need to run `updateCustomMarkers` when the map is ready, somehow though you've copied [our demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/), you're missing this critical line:

```js
chart.events.on( "ready", updateCustomMarkers );
```

With that in place, it should work each time whether on your site or the CMS.